# Status updates in organic groups disappear after a period of time

Tags: organic-groups, 7

After about 30 days or so, the activity streams under the Organic Group Home tab drop off or disappear. I have found a reference to this issue on Acquia Commons' [community site](http://commons.acquia.com/discussion/no-visible-status-updates-stream-activity-stream).

I have checked the view `activity_log_stream` but do not see where we might adjust the length of time which content remains on the activity stream. Optimally, we'd like the content to disappear only after the Items per page attribute is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **/admin/settings/activity_log** there is just the field to control this.

Note: Though each time we run a cron job, entries over 30 days still disappear. This is perhaps a bug? So our makeshift solution is to click the **Regenerate Activity** tag. This seems to behaves predictably.

[image]